# Div container with commentbox

Tags: html, css

Is it possible that the commentfield is in the bottom of commentbox, and if there is more comments then the commentfield will be in the bottom. Right bnow the comments is behind the commentbox.

```
#ProfileComments {
border: 1px solid #dfe0e4;
background: #fff;
width: 420px;
min-height: 308px;
position:relative;
}

#ProfileComments .commentfield {
position:absolute;
bottom: 0;
border: 1px solid #dfe0e4;
font-size:13px;
margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
padding: 5px;
width: 380px;
left: 0;
color: #4e5665;
}

<div id="ProfileComments">
    <div class="headline">Comments</div>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 265px;">
    <div class="picture"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="comment">
    <div class="author"><a href="">name</a><span class="date">date</span></div>

            Comment text
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: As long as you have absolute positioning of the comment box it will be cemented to that location not matter what goes on "behind" it. I Think I'd go with an approach of limiting the height of the comments and have a scrollbar on that and then use relative positioning for the comment box and the comments.

Comment: But is the other solution not possible? How do I position the commentbox at the bottom without the absoulte tag?

Comment: As far as I can make out you want it to Always be in the bottom of the comments. If so, yes, the short answer is, don't use absolute positioning on the comments box.